# Outlook AppointmentItem.PropertyChange not firing always

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Outlook AppointmentItem.PropertyChange not firing sometime, but MailItem.PropertyChange is firing always.

Comment: What is the actual code you've used?

Comment: _propertyChangehandlerSubject = (string str) =>
            {
                if (str.Equals("ConversationTopic"))
                {
                    subjectEventHandler();
                }
            };

Comment: appointmentItem.PropertyChange += _propertyChangehandlerSubject;

Comment: it is not clear where the appointment item instance comes from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the source appointment item at the global scope (for example, at the class level) to prevent it from being swiped from the heap by the GC. Otherwise, as soon as method ends and GC swipes it out from the heap you will not get the events fired.

The [PropertyChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867180.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event is fired when an explicit built-in property of the parent object is changed. Make sure the source appointment item object is alive as long as you need to get events handled.

The [Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973716%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) discusses a technique to implement an inspector wrapper. An inspector wrapper handles multiple instances of Microsoft Outlook inspector windows.

You may also find the [ItemChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865866.aspx) event of the Items class helpful. It is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed.

Comment: Hi,I need to fire whenever subject of appointment item is changed.So it fires on subject change in inconsistent manner ,but for mailItem it works fine.

Comment: I am working on C# Addin project.

Comment: You need to post the sample code which can be used for reproducing the issue.

Comment: _propertyChangehandlerSubject = (string str) =>
            {
                if (str.Equals("ConversationTopic"))
                {
                    subjectEventHandler();
                }
            };

Comment: if (item is AppointmentItem)
            {
                AppointmentItem appointmentItem = (AppointmentItem)item;
                appointmentItem.PropertyChange += _propertyChangehandlerSubject;

Comment: private ItemEvents_10_PropertyChangeEventHandler _propertyChangehandlerSubject;

Comment: You need to declare the source appointment item at the global scope (for example, at the class level) to prevent it from being swiped from the heap by the GC. Otherwise, as soon as method ends and GC swipes it out from the heap you will not get the events fired.

Comment: Astafiev  , declaring it on global scope is working fine.Thanks!

Comment: Glad my post helped!